# CodenameOne filter optimization on set of containers

Tags: asynchronous, spinner, codenameone

In my app, I have a searchbox which allows users to filter as they type.  For some reason I can't get an `InfinteProgress` to properly display while the filtering is being executed.
Here's my code:

**Pass 1**

```
public void renderForumList(){
        try{
            magnify = mStateMachine.findForumSearchIcon(form);
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            System.out.println("User typed additional character in search term before previous term finished executing");
        }
        InfiniteProgress infi = new InfiniteProgress();
        magnify.getParent().replace(magnify, infi, null);
        Display.getInstance().invokeAndBlock(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0;i < containerStates.length;i++){
                    if(containerStates[i] != listItems[i].isVisible()){
                        listItems[i].setHidden(!containerStates[i]);
                        listItems[i].setVisible(containerStates[i]);
                    }
                }
                Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                     mStateMachine.findForumsListComponent(form).animateLayout(200);
                    mStateMachine.findContainer2(form).replace(infi, magnify, null);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
}
```

In this version, the infinite progress shows up in the proper position, but it doesn't spin.

**Pass 2**

```
public void renderForumList(){
        try{
            magnify = mStateMachine.findForumSearchIcon(form);
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            System.out.println("User typed additional character in search term before previous term finished executing");
        }
        InfiniteProgress infi = new InfiniteProgress();
        magnify.getParent().replace(magnify, infi, null);
                for (int i = 0;i < containerStates.length;i++){
                    if(containerStates[i] != listItems[i].isVisible()){
                        listItems[i].setHidden(!containerStates[i]);
                        listItems[i].setVisible(containerStates[i]);
                    }
                }
        mStateMachine.findForumsListComponent(form).animateLayout(200);
        mStateMachine.findContainer2(form).replace(infi, magnify, null);
                    }
            }
}
```

In this version, the magnifier icon just flashes briefly, but the `InfiniteProgress` spinner is never visible.

I get the same results on the simulator and on an Android device.

How can I get the `InfiniteProgress` to spin while the search is taking place?

Answer (score 0):

`invokeAndBlock` opens a new thread and thus violates the EDT as you access UI components on a separate thread.

Try using `callSerially` instead to postpone the following code into the next EDT cycle although I'm not sure that will help as everything is still happening on the EDT.

Alternatively I'm guessing the method `isVisible` takes time, so you can enclose that call alone in `invokeAndBlock`.

To understand `invokeAndBlock` check out the developer guide https://www.codenameone.com/manual/edt.html

Comment: If I understand you right, there is no way to show an `InfiniteProgress` while rendering the UI?  Is that correct?

Comment: No. That is NOT what I said... I said accessing UI components should be done on the EDT. Other stuff off the EDT. I suggest reading the EDT chapter.